# ZonedDateTime Error between 2020 and 2021

Tags: jenkins, java-11

I have a problem with ZonedDateTime into my jenkins server.

since the 2021-01-01, my test failed on a compare date ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(10) and ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(5).

ZonedDateTime.now().plusDays(5) return like it should 2021-01-06
But ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(10) return **2021**-12-22

And in my intellij, the ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(10) return 2020-12-22.

I don't understand what happen but since the 1st january 2021 my test failed everydays.

Someone have an answer ?

thanks you by advence.

Comment: My guess is that you're making a mistake in formatting the year and use week-based-year `Y` instead of just year `u`.

Comment: the format is juste like that: `ZonedDateTime.now().minusDays(10).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/YYYY"))`

Comment: And that's exactly the problem. `Y` doesn't mean what you think it means. Use `/uuuu` at the end of your pattern.

Comment: ok I'll try it and come back to you, thank you @JoachimSauer

Comment: It works thank you but I didn't understand why change year-of-era by year  is working ?

Comment: To be honest I haven't looked at the specific values, but it's got to do with [alternate date systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) ([video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D3jxx8Yyw1c)).